# How do I reduce the granularity of locking while maintaining thread safety?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple, managed group of Stacks that need to be accessed in a thread-safe manner. My first implementation is working correctly but uses `synchronized` methods for all access, ie. locking is at the most coarse level. I'd like to make locking as granular as possible but I'm unsure of the best way to go about it.

Here's the basics of my Stack manager class (with some details elided for brevity):

```
public class StackManager {
    private final Map<String, Deque<String>> myStacks;
    public StackManager() {
        myStacks = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Deque<String>>();
    }
    public synchronized void addStack(String name) {
        if (myStacks.containsKey(name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        myStacks.put(name, new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String>());
    }
    public synchronized void removeStack(String name) {
        if (!myStacks.containsKey(name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        myStacks.remove(name);
    }
    public synchronized void push(String stack, String payload) {
        if (!myStacks.containsKey(stack)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        myStacks.get(stack).push(payload);
    }
    public synchronized String pop(String stack) {
        if (!myStacks.containsKey(stack)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return myStacks.get(stack).pop();
    }
}
```

The stack-level methods (addStack(), removeStack()) are not used that often. However I'd like to know if their level of locking can be reduced. For example, if these methods were unsynchronized and established a lock on `myStacks` would this reduce contention? For example,

```
    public void addStack(String name) {
        synchronized(myStacks) {
            if (myStacks.containsKey(name)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            myStacks.put(name, new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String>());
        }
    }
```

The per-stack methods (push(), pop()) are where I feel the most gains can be made. I'd like to achieve per-stack locking if I could. That is, only lock the single stack within the stack manager that is being operated on. However I cannot see a good way to do this. Any suggestions?

While we're here, is it necessary to use the concurrent implementations of both Map and Deque?

Comment: Why do you want to make locking more granular? Do you have a performance problem, and has benchmarking shown lock contention to be a bottleneck?

Comment: Fair question. I suppose it's partly academic, but there is also some evidence of contention in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Both data structures are thread safe. So, every isolated operation on the is thread safe.

The problem is performing more than one operation when there's a dependency between them.

In your case, checking for existance must be atomic with the actual operation to avoid race conditions.
To add a new stack, you can use the method putIfAbsent, which is atomic and not synchronized.

To remove a stack, you don't need to check for existance. If you want to know whether it existed, just return remove method return value. If it's null, it didn't exist.

To perform push and pop, you just have to get the stack first and assign to a local variable. If it's null, it didn't exist. If it's nonnull, you can safely push or pop.

The attribute myStacks must be either final or volatile to be thread safe.

Now you don't need any synchronization. And I would choose a solution without exceptions. Only to add a new stack it seems more necessary. If it can happen in a correct program, it should be a checked exception. Runtime exception is more suitable when it is supposed to be a bug.

Oh, and triplecheck and test it, as concurrent programming is tricky.

Comment: `myStacks` is `final` in the actual code. I transcribed it to my question incorrectly. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can I get a reference to a particular stack in (say) `push()` if this stack can be removed by `removeStack()` at the same time?

Comment: Yes, Java does not delete objects explicitely, just when nobody references them

Comment: I don't think I was clear in my question: is it thread-safe to get a reference to a stack (via `myStacks.get()`) if that stack can be removed from `myStacks` by a call to `removeStack()`?

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe. This means get is thread safe. When you invoke get, and very close in time there's a remove, there are only to options: remove happens befor or after get. If it happens before, get returns null and you can do whatever you find best: return null or throw an exception. If remove happens after get, you actually get a reference to the stack. removeStack removes the reference to the stack in the map, but your reference is still valid. You perform the operation desired on the stack and, when your method returns, your reference is out of scope and,

Comment: when there's no reference left, the stack will become inaccesdible and eventually garbage collected. No problem. The same would happen if it were deleted right after your thread returns.